# Region filter in config is not honoured by DescribeSnapshots

Tags: aws-sdk-go

Even after configuring the region explicitly, SDK seems to report more snapshots than visible in the AWS console. It seems like it returns snapshot data from all regions for the account.

```
  sess := session.Must(session.NewSessionWithOptions(session.Options{
        Config: aws.Config{Region: aws.String("eu-central-1"),Endpoint: aws.String("ec2.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com")},
    }))
  svc := ec2.New(sess, &aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String(endpoints.EuCentral1RegionID),
  })
  input := &ec2.DescribeSnapshotsInput{
      Filters: []*ec2.Filter{
        &ec2.Filter{
          Name: aws.String("status"),
          Values: []*string{aws.String("completed")},
        },
      },
  }

  result, err := svc.DescribeSnapshots(input)
  if err != nil {
      if aerr, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
          switch aerr.Code() {
          default:
              fmt.Println(aerr.Error())
          }
      } else {
          fmt.Println(err.Error())
      }
  }

  for _, snapshot := range result.Snapshots{
    fmt.Println(*snapshot.SnapshotId, " : ", *snapshot.VolumeSize)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Followed the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSnapshots.html) and understood that DescribeSnapshots returns three types of snapshots. a) Public Snapshots (Made publicly available for volume creation by somebody else) b) Explicit Snapshots (Made available explicitly to your AWS account by somebody else) c) Implicit Snapshots (Snapshots created by your own account)

Hence, there are lot more results than expected.

Additionaly, if you pass the following filter to DescribeSnapshotsInput:

```
&ec2.Filter{
  Name: aws.String("owner-id"),
  Values:[]*string{aws.String("XXXXYYYYYZZZZ")},
},
```

the results are further reduced to show snapshots that are only available in your region